# setState does not update state immediately inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build an analog clock with the second hand rotating every second, min hand rotating 6deg every minute and hour hand rotating 6deg every 12 minutes.

Here's the codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-d7mes?file=/Clock.js

Whenever the min hand's angle is either of these `[72, 144, 216, 288, 360]` (12 minute degrees), I rotate the hour hand by 6 degrees once.

This is what I'm doing:

```
 let twelveMinDegrees = [72, 144, 216, 288, 360];

 setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prev => ({
            sec: prev.sec == 360 ? 6 : prev.sec + 6,  //degrees
            min: prev.sec == 354 ? (prev.min == 360 ? 6 : prev.min + 6) : prev.min,  //degrees
            hrs: (function(){  //degrees

                const indx = twelveMinDegrees.findIndex(el => el == prev.min)
                if(!minChanged && indx >=0){ //only change once for every 12min
                    minChanged = true; 
                    let incHrs = prev.hrs + (6*indx);
                    console.log(incHrs);
                    return incHrs; 
                }else{
                    if(!twelveMinDegrees.includes(prev.min)){
                        minChanged = false;
                    }
                    return prev.hrs;
                }
            })()
         }))
    }, 1000)
```

But the hour hand does not change and is set back to the previous value in the else part **the second time** and the value returned `incHrs` is neglected because before the state is updated, the `else` is called the next second which returns `prev.hrs` which is still the old value(not the value returned in the `if(!minChanged && indx >=0)`)

How do I fix this?

Comment: setTimeout and setInterval timing can vary widely.  You should not depend on it to track time.  Extract the time from Date(), or use the timestamp to calculate timing.

Comment: The issue I see with the hour not moving is that you get the current hour in the beginning and convert it to degrees(Without taking into account the current minutes). Then in your method, you are checking if it is only at a specific twelveMinDegrees. So if the time is not currently at one of those degrees, it will sit at the initial hour and not move until it hits one of those degrees(returning the previous hour). You should have an initial load to set the right degree. If you change over to using date, then you could have hour set as hrs * 30 + time.getMinutes() /2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental design problem here which is that [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is the wrong tool for keeping time. `setInterval` only guarantees that the callback won't run for *at least* 1000 milliseconds, not that it will run *exactly in* 1000 milliseconds, so you're going to wind up with drift and skipped times.

I recommend using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) library or [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) to determine when ticks have occurred.

With this set up, you can scale the hour hand proportional to the number of minutes left in the hour with:

```
(hours + minutes / 60) * 30 + 180
```

If you want a rougher granularity to the hour hand adjustments, truncate the minutes into 6 distinct chunks:

```
(hours + floor(minutes / 10) * 10 / 60) * 30 + 180
```

Doing this mathematically is much less messy than looking up the increment points in a hardcoded array.

Here's a minimal example which you could use to keep accurate time (I'll leave styling to you):

```css
.hand {
  width: 2px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: top center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.analog-clock {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/babel" defer>
const {Fragment, useEffect, useState, useRef} = React;

const Clock = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const requestRef = useRef();
  let prevDate = null;
  
  const tick = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    
    if (prevDate && now.getSeconds() !== prevDate.getSeconds()) {
      setDate(now);
    }
    
    prevDate = now;
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current);
  }, []);
  
  const pad = n => n.toString().padStart(2, 0);
  
  const computeHourDeg = date => 
    (date.getHours() + ~~(date.getMinutes() / 10) * 10 / 60) * 30 + 180
  ;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="analog-clock">
        <div
          className="hand"
          style={{transform: `rotate(${6 * date.getSeconds() + 180}deg)`}}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="hand"
          style={{transform: `rotate(${6 * date.getMinutes() + 180}deg)`}}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="hand"
          style={{background: "red", 
                  height: "30%",
                  transform: `rotate(${computeHourDeg(date)}deg)`}}
        ></div>
      </div>
      <h3>
        {pad(date.getHours())}:
        {pad(date.getMinutes())}:
        {pad(date.getSeconds())}
      </h3>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.body);

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a sped-up version with a mocked `Date` object to illustrate that it's working correctly:

```css
.hand {
  width: 2px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: top center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.analog-clock {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/babel" defer>
const {Fragment, useEffect, useState, useRef} = React;

const speedMS = 5;

class MockDate {
  static second = 0;
  static minute = 0;
  static hour = 0;
  
  constructor() {
    this.second = MockDate.second;
    this.minute = MockDate.minute;
    this.hour = MockDate.hour;
  }
  
  getSeconds() {
    return this.second;
  }
  
  getMinutes() {
    return this.minute;
  }
  
  getHours() {
    return this.hour || 12;
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  if (++MockDate.second === 60) {
    MockDate.second = 0;

    if (++MockDate.minute === 60) {
      MockDate.minute = 0;
      MockDate.hour = (MockDate.hour + 1) % 12;
    }
  }
}, speedMS);

const Clock = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new MockDate());
  const requestRef = useRef();
  let prevDate = null;

  const tick = () => {
    const now = new MockDate();

    if (prevDate && now.getSeconds() !== prevDate.getSeconds()) {
      setDate(now);
    }

    prevDate = now;
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current);
  }, []);

  const pad = n => n.toString().padStart(2, 0);

  const computeHourDeg = date => 
    (date.getHours() + ~~(date.getMinutes() / 10) * 10 / 60) * 30 + 180
  ;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="analog-clock">
        <div
          className="hand"
          style={{transform: `rotate(${6 * date.getSeconds() + 180}deg)`}}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="hand"
          style={{transform: `rotate(${6 * date.getMinutes() + 180}deg)`}}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="hand"
          style={{background: "red", 
                  height: "30%",
                  transform: `rotate(${computeHourDeg(date)}deg)`}}
        ></div>
      </div>
      <h3>
        {pad(date.getHours())}:
        {pad(date.getMinutes())}:
        {pad(date.getSeconds())}
      </h3>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.body);

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```